# Optimal Winsorizing Cutoffs for a stratified proportional to size population estimator.

Tags: st.statistics

I'm not familiar with the subject, but here's my question.
Is there any reference in the literature of Winsorized Type II
for total population estimator in a estratified with clustering proportional to size sample design? I want to try something like Kokic& Bell (1994). My estimator is like the following
$\sum_{h}\frac{1}{n_h}\sum_{i}\frac{M_{hi}}{z_{hi}}\frac{1}{m_{ehi}}\sum_{j}y_{hij}$

and would like to replace $y_{hij}$ with its winsorized $y_{hij}^*$. The problem
arises when i try to find the cut-offs that minimize the Mean Squared Error at that level.

Comment: I think you will have better luck at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions 

Comment: Thank you Jagy. Anyway, any experience in trying to deal with outliers in this way would be a great Help too.